# wrting double problem to excel

Tags: c#, excel, number-formatting

i have a text and i try to write this text to excel file by c#. this text include not one kind of value. i mean, it can be include "abc" "1.6", "1/6" etc. when i write 1.86 or 1/86 i see "feb.86" in the excel.  but i want to see what i write to. what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you writing it as delimited? xlsx? What?

Comment: Please post some sample code showing how you are setting the values in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

for numbers like 1/86 you can prefix it with **'**. But then you will get "Number Stored as Text" error in excel (little green triangle in cell). Otherwise you can always put things in double quotes to work:

```
="1/86"
```

PS:- procede with "**=**"